# How to remove gaps in a 2D map

Tags: arrays, dictionary, 2d

Using an algorithm, I procedurally create a 2D map of booleans in which 1 represents block/wall and 0 represents empty space.

Problem is, my algorithm generates some gaps that I would like to eliminate. What I mean is something like this

```
111
101
111
```

As you can see, there is a one cell in middle of walls. I like it to change into this:

```
111
111
111
```

How can I achieve it?

Thanks.

Comment: What is this "map" supposed to represent? How do you define a "gap"? Empty space surrounded by wall on opposite sides?

Comment: Map is just a 2D array of booleans, where one dimension would represent width and another would represent height of the game world.

I also fixed the gap representation in my question as well.

Based on values on this array, I'll draw the game map later on and I have to eliminate these gaps for another purpose.

Comment: So then you'd define a gap as an open space adjacent to eight wall spaces? What part of coding it are you having trouble with?

Comment: I like to find a way on how to detect these gaps on the 2D array so I would be able to fill them with 1's.

Problem is they will not always be simple cases like the one I mentioned in my question and the amount of empty space or gap can be in any shape or amount like:

  code>   0000000
  inline   0111110
  inline   0000000

or 
    000
    0100
    0100
    0110
    0100

And the algorithm should be able to find all these empty enclosed spaces.

Comment: I can't read the examples in your last comment due to the formatting. Are you trying to point out that these "gaps" may consist or more than one space? If so, are you actually looking for reachability from some specific starting point?

Comment: Tried my best to format my codes, did not work. I was trying to demonstrate that these gaps may have any shape and size.

About your second question, if I understood your question correctly, no, I'm not. I just want to be able to find them and fill them with 1's.

Comment: Only a restricted subset of Markdown formatting is available in comments. You can [edit] your question and put the examples there if they add new information. My point about reachability is that once your "gaps" can take on arbitrary shape and size, it becomes less clear what you consider one. What's your definition?

Comment: Definition would be that if there is one ore more 1 that is surrounded by 0's. In another word, if there is a '0' that is not reachable by at least one other '0' in the 2D integer array.

Comment: Did you mean "one or more `0` that is surrounded by `1`s" rather than the other way around? Your second sentence, on the other hand, implies that if there's any gap, then all `0`s are part of some gap (since the map is not path-connected). The most logical way to handle this is to specify a starting point. By the way, are diagonal moves moves allowed?

Comment: OK, Thanks @Jerry, I think I've explained this simple problem enough. Let's see how others will reply, if they may.

Comment: Listen, I don't hope this doesn't come across as condescending, but I think part of the issue is that you either haven't completely formulated what you're trying to accomplish or you haven't been able to fully describe your formulation in the question. Addressing that will increase the likelihood that you get a good answer. I'll leave this question alone now, good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing something similar to Flood-fill algorithm with optimizations to make it feasible for games.